# gcc -fvisibility problem

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, exception

I have the problem described here:

http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility

Exception class exported from shared library cannot be caught when used outside of the library, and the program terminates. I added  `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` to the class declaration:

```
class  __attribute__((visibility("default"))) MyException
{
    ...
};
```

But this doesn't help. Client executable does not catch this exception. 
gcc version is 4.4.1, used in the Linux OS.

Comment: If more than one linked object has a `MyException`, it must be visible in all of them, not just the one(s) that throw it --- any hidden definitions will override any default-visible ones.

Comment: Sorry, don't not understand what you mean.

Comment: Actually, I am not sure that the problem is visibility. There is something else, which prevents the client to catch this exception, and it is GCC-specific. The same code runs successfully under MSVC. Runtime error looks like this: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'MyException'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: this was not visibility problem. I got an answer here:
[Exceptions are not caught in GCC program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424836/exceptions-are-not-caught-in-gcc-program)